# Delete directories older than X days?

Tags: python

I decided to go python for this because I am in the process of learning Python, so I use it over Powershell whenever I can.

I have the theory down for this, but it seems `os.stat` cannot take a list, but only a string or `int`.  Right now I'm just printing before I go and delete things.

```
import os
import time

path = "\\\\path\\to\\videoroot\\"
now = time.time()
old = now - 1296000

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    if time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(dirs) < old:
        print (dirs)
```

Output/error message:

```
return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
    TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not list
```

Comment: Not asking why, I'm asking how, but thank your for your less than constructive input.

Comment: i am sorry there are nasty people such as Nick. I found that the issue is poor education in some people. 
So yeah is a list. I am also dealing with a similar issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code problem is that you are passing `dirs` to `os.path.getmtime()`, and `dirs` is a `list` as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) for `os.walk`

So you can address this by:

```
import os
import time

path = "\\\\path\\to\\videoroot\\"
now = time.time()
old = now - 1296000

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for _dir in dirs:
        if os.path.getmtime(_dir) < old:
            print (_dir)
```

Comment: ah, i see what you are doing there.  I'll give it a go.  Thank you!

Comment: @martimeai typically you have to verify it met your needs.  In this case it did, his answer has been accepted.

Comment: @sal Thank you, I understand what I was doing wrong, great example.